# Django+gunicorn+nginx upload large file 502 error

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

## Problem

Uploading 1-2mb files works fine.
When I attempt to upload 16mb file, i get 502 error after several seconds

More detalied:

1. I click "Upload"
2. Google Chrome uploads file (upload status is changing from 0% to 100% in left bottom corner)
3. Status changes to "Waiting for HOST", where HOST is my site hostname
4. After a half of minute server returns "502 Bad Gateway"

#### My view:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = File(data=request.FILES['file'])
        f.save()
        return redirect(reverse(display),  f.id)
    else:
        return render('filehosting_upload.html', request)
```

render(template, request [,data]) is my own shorthand that deals with some ajax stuff;

The `filehosting_upload.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h2>File upload</h2>
    <form action="{% url nexus.filehosting.views.upload %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Upload</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

## Logs & specs

There are nothing informative in logs i can find.

Versions:

- Django==1.4.2
- Nginx==1.2.1
- gunicorn==0.17.2

Command line parameters

```
command=/var/www/ernado/data/envs/PROJECT_NAME/bin/gunicorn -b localhost:8801 -w 4 PROJECT_NAME:application
```

Nginx configuration for related location:

```
   location /files/upload {
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    proxy_pass http://HOST;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;
   }
```

#### Nginx log entry (changed MY_IP and HOST)

```
2013/03/23 19:31:06 [error] 12701#0: *88 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: MY_IP, server: HOST, request: "POST /files/upload HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8801/files/upload", host: "HOST", referrer: "http://HOST/files/upload"
```

#### Django log

```
2013-03-23 19:31:06 [12634] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:12829)
2013-03-23 19:31:06 [12634] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:12829)
2013-03-23 19:31:06 [13854] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13854
```

## Question(s)

1. how to fix that?
2. is it possible to fix that without nginx upload module?

**Update 1**
Tried suggested config

```
 gunicorn --workers=3 --worker-class=tornado  --timeout=90 --graceful-timeout=10 --log-level=DEBUG --bind localhost:8801 --debug
```

Works fine for me now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I run my gunicorn with that parameters, try :

```
python manage.py run_gunicorn --workers=3 --worker-class=tornado  --timeout=90 --graceful-timeout=10 --log-level=DEBUG --bind 127.0.0.1:8151 --debug
```

or if you run differently, you may run with that options

Comment: Thanks, worked for me with
gunicorn --workers=4 --worker-class=tornado  --timeout=90 --graceful-timeout=10 --log-level=DEBUG --bind localhost:8801 --debug

Comment: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8152 --debug --log-level debug -w=2 --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=server.settings --log-file=- --preload

Comment: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 127.0.0.1:8152 --debug --log-level debug -w=2  --worker-class=gevent --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=server.settings --log-file=- --preload

Answer (score 3):

For large files handling you should use a **worker-class**. Also I had some trouble using gevent in python 3.7, better to use 3.6.

**Django, Python 3.6 example:**

*Install*:

```
pip install gevent
```

*Run*

```
gunicorn --chdir myApp myApp.wsgi --workers 4 --worker-class=gevent --bind 0.0.0.0:80 --timeout=90 --graceful-timeout=10
```

Comment: Would using one of the new asgi servers (uvicorn etc) fix this without needing Gevent?

Comment: Also interested in the answer to @aroooo  's comment. Also, is there any modification to do in the Django' s project functions? What about the "monkey patch"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to used an other worker type class an async one like **gevent** or **tornado** see this for more explanation :
First explantion :

> You may also want to install Eventlet or Gevent if you expect that your application code may need to pause for extended periods of time during request processing

Second one :

> The default synchronous workers assume that your application is resource bound in terms of CPU and network bandwidth. Generally this means that your application shouldn’t do anything that takes an undefined amount of time. For instance, a request to the internet meets this criteria. At some point the external network will fail in such a way that clients will pile up on your servers.